# dcast replicate in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big pandas data frame something like as follows:

```
col1     col2     col3    col4
 a        d        sd       2
 b        sd       sd       2
 a        ds       hg       3
 a        ew       rt       3
 b        ss       qq       4
```

I want the output similar to the following:

```
col1     sum
a        8
b        6
```

'sum' column has the summation of all values of col4 for unique values of col1. 
In R this can be done using `dcast`

```
dcast(dataframe, col1 ~ count, sum, value.var = 'col4')
```

How do i do this in python?

Comment: Are you looking for [Group By: split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby)?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is what's described in [Group By: split-apply-combine](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#groupby):

```
groups = df.groupby('col1')
splitgroups = groups['col4']
sums = splitgroups.aggregate(np.sum)
```

Or, more directly:

```
sums = df.groupby('col1').aggregate({'col4': np.sum})
```

But read the whole page instead; the Pandas `groupby` feature is more flexible than R `dcast` (it's designed to also accomplish everything SQL aggregation, Excel pivots, etc. can do), but that means your ideas may not always map one-to-one between the two.

Here it is in action:

```
>>> # your DataFrame, with a default index
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': 'a b a a b'.split(), 'col2': 'd sd ds ew ss'.split(), 'col3': 'sd sd hg rt qq'.split(), 'col4': (2, 2, 3, 3, 4)})
>>> sums = df.groupby('col1').aggregate({'col4': np.sum})
>>> sums
      col4
col1
a        8
b        6
```

Comment: you want to put up a PR to add this to the docs here? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_r.html

Comment: @Jeff: I'm not sure what exactly should be added. Pandas documentation probably doesn't need to discuss the differences between `dcast` and `aggregate` in R, but how would you explain this otherwise? Well, I guess I can just open the issue and leave it up to someone else to fix. :)

Comment: that section I pointed is kind of a reference for R people transitioning to pandas. This would be a nice addition.